# How would I interact with stateful API if the states in redux should be immutable?

Tags: redux, react-redux

So in this app, I am using the MediaRecorder api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). I am trying to use React-Redux as a framework for the site. The following is a simplified version of my reducer to illustrate my question:

```
(state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "START_RECORDING":
            return new MediaRecorder(...).start();
        case "STOP_RECORDING":
            state.stop(); <--- is this ok?
            return {};
    }
    return state;
})
```

So I read that the redux state should be immutable. However, I have to somehow stop the media recorder so that it stops recording stuff. Is this `state.stop()`  ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's definitely a bad pattern to follow.

Per the Redux FAQ, [your store state *should* only be plain serializable JS data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable).  So, you might track a value like `{playing : true}` in the store, but you shouldn't actually keep a class instance in there.

The "right" way to do this would be to have a React component that wraps around the imperative MediaRecorder API, receives values from the Redux store as props, and calls the MediaRecorder functions in its React lifecycle methods, like `componentWillReceiveProps`.  I show some examples of how to do this in my blog post [Declaratively Rendering Earth in 3D, Part 2: Controlling Cesium with React](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/03/declarative-earth-part-2-cesium-react/), and I have links to other similar articles in the [React Component Patterns#Wrapping Non-React Code](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-component-patterns.md#wrapping-non-react-code) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).

A quick example might look like:

```
class MediaRecorderWrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        if(this.props.playing) {
            this.mediaRecorder.start();
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.playing !== this.props.playing) {
            if(nextProps.playing) {
                this.mediaRecorder.start();
            }
            else {
                this.mediaRecorder.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

const mapState = (state) => {
    return {
        playing : state.playing
    };
}

export default connect(mapState)(MediaRecorderWrapper);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am wondering if this really needs to be a component since it could be just a javascript class which provide the media recorder as a service. (I have more experience in angular so I though service pattern would be a good idea? not sure about in react redux)

Comment: The biggest reason to make it a React component is to make use of React's lifecycle methods for controlling the MediaRecorder instance, and React-Redux to handle the subscription to the store.  You could certainly do the same approach with a plain JS class, but you'd have to implement the store subscription logic and lifecycle handling yourself.